# Find and replace a character in xml file using sed command is not working

Tags: command-line, sed

I have an xml file called myfile.xml

```
<!--This is an xml document for test-->
<a><!--This is root node-->
   <b>
     <c>Hi&Welcome</c>
   </b>
   <d>Hello & How are you?</d>
</a>
```

I want this transformation

```
<!--This is an xml document for test-->
<a><!--This is root node-->
   <b>
     <c>Hi&amp;Welcome</c>
   </b>
   <d>Hello &amp; How are you?</d>
</a>
```

I am using sed command as follows to change all occurrences of & into &

```
sed -i 's:&:&amp;:' myfile.xml
```

but I am getting `undefined label 'yfile.xml' error. I am unable to proceed further. How to do this?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me. Are you using GNU `sed`?

Comment: Works here. Can't see the problem.

Comment: @kos -  I am using linux

Comment: something like `sed -i 's:&:&amp:;'thefile.xml` will result in such a message. Is this the exact command that you are using?

Comment: @adonis  - Yes. The exact command  I am using

Comment: Whats the output of `sed --version`?

Comment: That's because you're not using Ubuntu! You are probably on OSX or BSD and sed's `-i` option needs an argument. Please don't ask about non-Ubuntu OSs here. You can ask on [unix.se] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have *GNU sed*, `sed` needs an parameter for `-i`

```
sed -i.bak 's:&:&amp;:' myfile.xml
```

and a backup file is a good idea or …

… use Perl **;)**

Test with

```
perl -pe 's/&/&amp;/' myfile.xml
```

and make an **inplace edit** with

```
perl -pi -e 's/&/&amp;/' myfile.xml
```

**But only once.**

After the command, the content of `myfile.xml` is

```
<!--This is an xml document for test-->
<a><!--This is root node-->
   <b>
     <c>Hi&amp;Welcome</c>
   </b>
   <d>Hello &amp; How are you?</d>
</a>
```

Comment: Unaccepted? Why? Something wrong? I've added a new part. **;)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape & because of special character.  And you need two passes to complete it.

Use:
1.`sed  's|Hi\&|Hi\&amp;|g' yourfile.xml`. 
This will produces:

```
<!--This is an xml document for test-->
<a><!--This is root node-->
   <b>
     <c>Hi&amp;Welcome</c>
   </b>
   <d>Hello & How are you?</d>
</a>
```

2. The second pass will be:`sed  's|Hello\ \&| \Hello\ \&amp;|g' test.xml`. Produces:

   ```
   <!--This is an xml document for test-->
   <a><!--This is root node-->
      <b>
       <c>Hi&amp;Welcome</c>
      </b>
      <d> Hello &amp; How are you?</d>
   </a>
   ```

   Of course use `-i` switch to make it permenant.

Another advanced way based on @terdon comment below is:

`sed -e 's/Hello &/Hello \&amp;/' -e 's/Hi&/Hi\&amp;/' filename.xml`

Comment: Why would you need two passes? No need for `Hi` and `Hello` in the regex.

Comment: @Nephente, you are also right. There are a lot of way to edit the file using sed or perl or python. Why dont you improve the answer? Good to know others method.

Comment: You also don't need to escape `&`. `&` ins sed's `s///` operator means "whatever was matched", so in this particular case, since the OP is matching `&`, the `&` on the right hand side will actually be `&`. There is absolutely no reason to run two passes. In fact, the second pass will break the first and result in `Hi&amp;amp;Welcome`.

Comment: @terdon, tested on my box. it did not break the first pass. I trying to be more fundamental for the answer, easy to understand in POSIX way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I hadn't realized that you were using `Hello &`. No, it won't break on the second pass, it's just not needed. The OP wants to replace `&` with `&amp;`, why specify only two specific ones? What if there are others in the file? Also, you still don't need two passes: `sed 's/Hello &/Hello \&amp;/;s/Hi&/Hi\&amp;/` or, POSIXLY `sed -e 's/Hello &/Hello \&amp;/' -e 's/Hi&/Hi\&amp;/`. In both cases though, you don't actually need to escape either the spaces or the `&` for the reason I explained above.

Comment: @terdon yup both way it works. I rather use perl than sed. :-P.  I tried to write the answer for beginner to undestand. Not too advanced. But yes, your method is correct as well. Less line of code indeed.

Comment: I think terdon's point is that using `Hello` or `Hi` in the pattern / replacement string defeats the use of `sed` in first place. Using `sed` is useful to do more than replacing fixed strings. Although replacing fixed strings with `sed` will work (unnecessarily complicated by the fact that any metacharacter in the pattern and (e.g.) backreferences in the replacement string should be escaped in order to be treated literally), to replace fixed strings simply `nano`, Gedit or whatever text editor with a search & replace function will suffice